# Ext.Net - Call the javascript function form code behind

Tags: javascript, extjs, ext.net

Is it possibile to call javascript function from DirectEvent in Ext.Net 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
X.Js.Call("myFunctionName", "param1", "param2");
```

Comment: Works fine for me! Thank's @Stefano Lonati

Comment: It's possible to create the javascript function that I want to call directly from code behind?

Comment: Ummm...interesting question... try this:  `string callbackScript = "function HelloFromJavascript(){alert('hello Javascript!!')}"; Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "HelloFromJavascript", callbackScript, true);`

Comment: Yeah! Work perfectly for me! Thanks again!

Comment: I noticed that this method is not working in ajaxEvent. There is a method to call a javascript function that show only one alert in this case?

Comment: In ajaxEvent the only way is to use: `Ext.Msg.Alert("Alert Header", "Alert Body").Show();`